# Why Global Variable DbContext cannot SaveChanges?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, savechanges

I have a class and define a concrete `DbContext` variable (global variable in class). But when I call `DbContext.SaveChanges()` method in some instance method, it will be blocked! I don't know why ....

Code looks like this:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public ERPEntities ERP { get; set; } // ERPEntities is DbContext type

    public void Execute()
    {
        //......
        ERP.SaveChanges(); // It will be blocked! will never proceed.
    }
}
```

However, if I use local `ERPEntities` variable in the method to call `SaveChanges`, the strange behavior will disappear!

Could you please tell me why? I think it's very important because in our project, I want to use a global `DbContext` variable to use because of frequently database calling.

Comment: what does "*It will be Blocked*" actually mean?. you shouldn't really need to cache a DbContext, unless this is injected and scoped in say like a controller or WCF service.

Comment: What are other places where ERP is used? Also, your optimization might not be actually useful, as DB connections are cached in a pool.

Comment: @TheGeneral, "It will be blocked" means that the program is blocked just looks like resource competition scenario. there is no any response but program is in the running state, very strange~~

Comment: @Euphoric, I just don't want to create new ERPEntities context object for each Insert/Delete/Update calling. I don't know whether it's low-performance for creating the context object each time when I insert, delete or update data into database, especially for frequent operations in batch. So I want to use a global context object. That is my original intention.

Comment: Can anybody tell me the reason why this scenario happened?